# Access static variables

Tags: java, static

I have a following scenario. There are two classes **class A** and **class B**. Both of the classes is of following nature.

## Class A

```
static public int a = 10;
static public int b = a-3;
```

## Class B

```
A.a = 5; 
// print b here.
```

## b = ?

Correct me if I got wrong somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: int is a plain type, not reference type. So when you do "b = a", you assign b to 10, not to a.

Comment: `Can anyone help me to set value of a so that it effect another static variable b` Impossible through field access. Java is pass by value.

Comment: You essentially set `b` to a copy of `a` at that point in time to whatever the value of `a` happens to be. You'd have to redefine `b` to what you want it to be.

Comment: As Sotirios has pointed out, the thing you have asked for is actually impossible.  But what are you actually trying to achieve?  There may be another way of doing it.

Comment: So, isn't it possible to change **b** as **a** change from another class.

Comment: You could make `a` and `b` both reference the same array of size one, then set the value inside it.  Does that meet your needs?  If not, please tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, so we can help.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question after people start answering it.  It's really not fair.  But the answer to your new question is 7.

Comment: Now the previous question is related with this question. How can I set value of **a** so that **b** is changed.

Comment: @BlackRabbitt, See my answer to your original question. It does not get around the problem mentioned by everyone here, but it might be sufficient for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. However, you can write a method that does this for the two variables:

```
private static void setValue(int value) {
    b = val;
    A.a = val;
}
```

If you insist of doing that "directly", consider moving to C/C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Even it is Object or primitive it is not possible, as java support **Pass By Value** not **Pass by Reference**.

Answer (score 1):

This might get to close to the behavior you want.

```
class IntWrapper {
    int inside;
    public IntWrapper(int i) {
        inside = i;
    }
}
class A {
    static IntWrapper a = new IntWrapper(10);
    static IntWrapper b = a;
}
public class B {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       A.a.inside = 5;
       System.out.println(A.b.inside);
   }
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, if there's only going to be a few possible values for `a` and `b` you could define an enum for them, import the enum and just use `a = Five` which is kind of crazy (and doesn't work so well with arithmetic, though you could create methods like `Minus` on the enum), but using an additional class just to get around using getters and setters is a little crazy too

Answer (score 0):

No. Even `static public Integer a = 10;`, which is a reference type, won't change this, because you're changing the object that the variable points to.

What you can do is set up getters and setters, a la C# properties:

```
private static int a;
private static int b;
public static int GetA() {return a;}
public static int SetA(int newA) {a = newA; b = newA}
public static int GetB() {return b;}
```

If you want `b` to then be just a calculation based on `a` this is really easy:

```
private static int a;
public static int GetA() {return a;}
public static int SetA(int newA) {a = newA;}
public static int GetB() {return a - 3;}
```

If you just want a single statement to update both, though, you can do it with

```
b = a = 3;
```

Not really that exciting though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    private static int a;
    private static int b;

    static {
        setAB(10);
    }

    public static int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public static int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public static void setAB(int value) {
        a = value;
        b = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are not in the same class.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Pretty sure they are. The set statement is in a different class, but both values are in class `A`.

Comment: this seems like more than what the op was asking for and not even an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

If `b` is a function of a .. why not just declare it is as a static function:

```
class A {
    static IntWrapper a = 10;
    public static getB(){
       return a - 3;
    }
}
```

This way it will update properly when `a` changes and
there will be no way to **set** `b` if you don't need that behavior.